# Capture values and send email trigger

Tags: google-apps-script

I managed to collect data of user typing in and by using `onChange` trigger, I did meet my requirements for my task. However, I realized that for example I am filling up Column A1:A4. If my A1:A3 is out of range, it will trigger the email. But if my A4 is within range, the values of A1:A3 will still trigger the email eventhough it has trigger it before. How do I make sure that the values that have been capture do not trigger the email again?

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  currentsheet = ss.getSheetName();
  //var values = ss.getRange(a1Notation)
  //console.log(values);
  var lastcol = ss.getLastColumn();
  var vibrationtemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("vibration");
  var temperaturetemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("temperature");
  //console.log(lastcol);


  if((currentsheet == 'A Vibration') || (currentsheet == 'B Vibration')){
    console.log(currentsheet);
    for(var i =2; i<=lastcol; i++){
     var cell = ss.getRange(i,lastcol).getValues();
      console.log(""+cell);

      if(cell > 8){
        console.log("Value is more than 8 and current value is "+cell);
        vibrationtemplate.vibrate = cell;
        MailApp.sendEmail("someone@gmail.com",
    "Parameter Out of Range Notification",
     "",{htmlBody: vibrationtemplate.evaluate().getContent()});
    }
      }
    }

  if((currentsheet == 'A Temperature') || (currentsheet == 'B Temperature')){
    console.log(currentsheet);
    for(var i =2; i<=lastcol; i++){
    var cell = ss.getRange(i,lastcol).getValues();
      console.log(""+cell);
      if(cell > 80){
        console.log("Value is more than 80 and current value is "+cell);
        temperaturetemplate.temp = cell;
        MailApp.sendEmail("someone@gmail.com",
    "Parameter Out of Range Notification",
     "",{htmlBody: temperaturetemplate.evaluate().getContent()});
    }
    }



  }
}
```

EDIT: Latest code - Using a daily trigger and only checks at the end of the day.

```
function myFunction() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var sheetNumber = sheets.length; //Get number of sheets within Spreadsheet
  var currentSheet = ss.getIndex()-1; //Get index of current sheet with 0 indexing
  var vibrationtemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("vibration"); //Create HTML for email by grabbing template from vibration.html
  var temperaturetemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("temperature"); //Create HTML for email by grabbing template from temperature.html

  const vibrationlimit = 8; //Set vibrationlimit as constant equals to 8
  const temperaturelimit = 80; //Set temperaturelimit as constant equals to 80

  var currentDate = new Date(); //Get system Date and Time
  var currentDay = currentDate.getDate(); //Extract Date from Full Date(currentDate)
  var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth() +1; //Extract Month from Full Date(currentDate), add +1 as month index start from 0.

  for (var z = currentSheet ; z<sheetNumber ; ++z ){

  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheets[z])
  var lastcol = sheets[z].getLastColumn();
  var lastrow= sheets[z].getLastRow();
  var cellDate = sheets[z].getRange(1,lastcol).getValues();
  var formattedCellDate = new Date(cellDate);
  var cellDay = formattedCellDate.getDate();
  var cellMonth = formattedCellDate.getMonth() + 1;

    if((z==0) || (z==2)){
      if((cellDay == currentDay) && (cellMonth == currentMonth)){ 
    for(var i = 2; i<=lastrow; i++){
     var scxvibrationname = sheets[z].getRange(i,1).getValues();
     var vibration = sheets[z].getRange(i,lastcol).getValues();
        if(vibration > vibrationlimit){
          Logger.log("Vibration over 8 - Current Value is "+vibration);
        vibrationtemplate.vibrate = vibration;
        vibrationtemplate.scxvibration = scxvibrationname;
        }

    }
      }

    }
}
```

Comment: Quickest way to avoid this is to maintain a **State** column which says "Email Sent" (or something else) and before triggering the email, check for the corresponding column to see if its empty or has a value.

Comment: But if I have 50 parameters for 1 day(50 rows of data in 1 column), I cannot have Email Sent for all the parameters. It will make the spreadsheet messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var sheetNumber = sheets.length; //Get number of sheets within Spreadsheet
  var currentSheet = ss.getIndex()-1; //Get index of current sheet with 0 indexing
  var vibrationtemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("vibration"); //Create HTML for email by grabbing template from vibration.html
  var temperaturetemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("temperature"); //Create HTML for email by grabbing template from temperature.html

  const vibrationlimit = 8; //Set vibrationlimit as constant equals to 8
  const temperaturelimit = 80; //Set temperaturelimit as constant equals to 80

  var currentDate = new Date(); //Get system Date and Time
  var currentDay = currentDate.getDate(); //Extract Date from Full Date(currentDate)
  var currentMonth = currentDate.getMonth() +1; //Extract Month from Full Date(currentDate), add +1 as month index start from 0.

  for (var z = currentSheet ; z<sheetNumber ; ++z ){

  SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSheet(sheets[z])
  var lastcol = sheets[z].getLastColumn();
  var lastrow= sheets[z].getLastRow();
  var cellDate = sheets[z].getRange(1,lastcol).getValues();
  var formattedCellDate = new Date(cellDate);
  var cellDay = formattedCellDate.getDate();
  var cellMonth = formattedCellDate.getMonth() + 1;

    if((z==0) || (z==2)){
      if((cellDay == currentDay) && (cellMonth == currentMonth)){ 
    for(var i = 2; i<=lastrow; i++){
     var scxvibrationname = sheets[z].getRange(i,1).getValues();
     var vibration = sheets[z].getRange(i,lastcol).getValues();
        if(vibration > vibrationlimit){
          Logger.log("Vibration over 8 - Current Value is "+vibration);
        vibrationtemplate.vibrate = vibration;
        vibrationtemplate.scxvibration = scxvibrationname;
        }

    }
      }

    }
}
```

I manipulated by using daily time-driven trigger.

Answer (score 0):

### You can use [PropertiesService](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties) to store the last row of the previous script run

The following code sets the start row for the `for` loop to the (last row+1) of the previous script run, so that only e-mails from newly added rows will be sent:

```
function myFunction() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  currentsheet = ss.getSheetName();
  //var values = ss.getRange(a1Notation)
  //console.log(values);
  var lastcol = ss.getLastColumn();
  var lastrow=ss.getLastRow();
  var vibrationtemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("vibration");
  var temperaturetemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("temperature");
  //console.log(lastcol);
        if(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getKeys().length==0){
           PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('startRow', lastrow+1);
         }
  var startRow=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('startRow');
  if((currentsheet == 'A Vibration') || (currentsheet == 'B Vibration')){
    console.log(currentsheet);
//I ASSUME THAT YOU WANT TO LOOP THROUGH ALL ROWS AND NOT COLUMNS
    for(var i =startRow; i<=lastrow; i++){
     var cell = ss.getRange(i,lastcol).getValues();
      console.log(""+cell);

      if(cell > 8){
        console.log("Value is more than 8 and current value is "+cell);
        vibrationtemplate.vibrate = cell;
        MailApp.sendEmail("someone@gmail.com",
    "Parameter Out of Range Notification",
     "",{htmlBody: vibrationtemplate.evaluate().getContent()});
    }
   }
  }
...
PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().setProperty('startRow', lastrow+1);
}
```

Comment: I put ``i = startRow`` and have a console.log, it apparently starts at row 65 and ends right away so technically the for loop doesn't even run. I then changed my ``i = 2``, it read all my data but got stuck at 65 again. My last row is 65 at this point.

Comment: The code above only send the emails for newly added rows. Since you have 65 rows already, it assumes that you already sent emails for those rows and won't send new emails until you add new rows. Is this not what you intended to do?

Comment: Rows will always be fixed based on how many parameters I have. The columns are always increasing as its added on certain date. I managed to manipulate it by using time driven trigger, which only triggers at the end of the day, which then checks the date that the column is vs the current day/month of the system. I'm able to get it the way i want, however, right now, I want it to keep going through all 4 sheets, instead of going through only on ``active`` spreadsheet.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a copy/ snippet of your sheet(s) for better understanding

Comment: @zigantoschka - I managed to somewhat make it work. Updated my question with the latest code. Only thing now is I'm trying to optimize it and try to put some stuff into a function to make it neat.